# OPA OAuth example

Tags: oauth, opa

I need to write an OPA application that authenticates the user via OAuth. Are there any examples or OPA libraries available?

Answer (score 2):

There is a OAuth 1.0a library in OPA. You can use it "import stdlib.apis.oauth"

You can see it's documentation at : http://opalang.org/resources/doc/index.html#oauth.opa.html/!/value_stdlib.apis.oauth.OAuth

If you want to interact with a website using OAuth 2.0, you don't nees any specific library since it works with a simple argument passed with your requests.

Comment: An example of authenticating using oauth2 would be helpful.